# Transactions and methods with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, transactions, sqlalchemy

I have a collection class which is used to modify some data in DB using SQLAlchemy:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

class Collection:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.engine = sa.create_engine(...)

    def get_some_name_by_id(self, name):
        return self.engine.execute(select(), ...).fetchone().id

    def add(self, name):
        some_id = self.get_some_name_by_id(name)
        with self.engine.begin() as conn:
            conn.execute(...)
            conn.execute(...)
            conn.execute(...)
            ...
```

So it has two methods:

- `get_some_name_by_id` - given a name returns some id
- `add` method uses id from the `get_some_name_by_id` to perform some series of SQL requests.

The problem is that I want to include `get_some_name_by_id` into the transaction. At first I had one giant `add` method where all `execute` statements where under the `with` statement. and now I am refactoring the code by extracting some chunks to the methods and I do not know how to I add them into transaction. If possible method should run in transaction if it's called within the transaction.

Sure I can do something like:

```
def get_some_name_by_id(self, name, conn=None):
    if conn is None:
        conn = self.engine
    return conn.execute(select(), ...).fetchone().id

def add(self, name):
    with self.engine.begin() as conn:
        some_id = self.get_some_name_by_id(name, conn)
        conn.execute(...)
```

But that looks a little bit clumsy to me. I'll end up with lot's of functions having this identical if clause. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think your suggested method is ok. You could use the @property decorator to implement custom retrieval for conn:
for example:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

class Collection(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.engine = sa.create_engine(...)
        self._conn = None

    @property
    def conn(self):
        if self._conn is None:
            self._conn = self.engine
        return self._conn

    @conn.setter
    def conn(self, value):
        self._conn = value

    def get_some_name_by_id(self, name):
        return self.conn.execute(select(), ...).fetchone().id

    def add(self, name):
        with self.engine.begin() as self.conn:
            some_id = self.get_some_name_by_id(name)
            self.conn.execute(...)
```

This way you don't have to pass conn around. You can initialize self.conn once and use it  Using this as is you'll be limited to one connection per Collection object. You could modify it to support multiple connections (if needed).

Comment: Hm, interesting solution. After a `with` block `self.conn` will become **None** or no?

Comment: self.conn will still be a connection object but you wont be able to use it for any other queries without calling `self.conn.begin()`. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.begin for what happens when begin is called

Comment: That's bad. Because it means I can't use `get_some_name_by_id` without a transaction.

Comment: You can still use `get_some_name_by_id` as a standalone outside of the transaction. You'll have to set self.conn to `None` at the end of `add()`. So the next time `self.conn` is accessed it will return `self.engine` and `.execute(...).fetchone()...` will still work.